# Past Simple vs Present Perfect for not finished period of time in AmE

Tags: american-english

everyone!
I googled this topic a lot but all materials I find are about BrE, textbooks about American grammar don't mention this situation.

Is it correct to say

"I drank three cups of coffee this morning (or today)"

in American English?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: If the time period is on going, you can say "I already drank three cups of coffee this morning. This has become common recently - [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+already+_VERB_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: Comparison with/without *have* - [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&content=I+already+_VERB_+%2C+I+have+already+_VERB_&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20already%20_VERB_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20already%20_VERB_%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can say:

> I **drank** three cups of coffee this morning [or "today"].

You would use this sentence is you perceive the action of drinking coffee to be *completed* or if the *morning has passed* (if you choose "this morning" instead of "today")

OR

> I **have drunk** three cups of coffee this morning [or "today"].

You would use this sentence is you perceive the action of drinking coffee to be *still occurring.*

***Whether you perceive the action as being "completed" or "still occurring" is your choice.***

---

***There are a few things we must consider before approaching this.***

First, we need to choose between "this morning" and "today."  *I will* address both of these in my answer.

Second, we must know what time of day it is; this tells us if it is still morning, or if the morning is in the past.  *I will* address both situations in my answer.

---

The **simple past** (or past indicative) is *typically* used to talk about things that happened (and were *completed*) at a specific point in the past.

***Note: the author/speaker can decide what constitutes "completed."***

For example, if it is ***either*** still the morning or no longer the morning, we can say the following:

> I **drank** three cups of coffee **this morning.**

Regardless of whether the morning has passed, we can use the simple past, but ***only if you perceive the action of drinking coffee to be complete.*** Then, the action (drinking coffee) happened at a specific point in the past (this morning), so the use of the simple past is warranted.

You can also use the simple past with "today" instead of "this morning."

> I **drank** three cups of coffee **today.**

As I stated above (when "this morning" was in the sentence), you can only use this tense if you are not going to drink any more coffee today.  This means that the action has been *completed* at a specific point in the past (today–but before now), which warrants the use of the simple past.

---

The **present perfect** is *typically* used to describe actions that began in the past and are still occurring.  The present perfect is formed with the verb "have" or "has" and the past participle of the verb.

***Note: the author/speaker can decide what constitutes "still occurring."***

For example:

> I **have drunk** three cups of coffee **today.**

The action (drinking coffee) began sometime today and is still occurring.  It is still occurring, so we don't want to say that it is completed (which would make us use the simple past).

If it is **still the morning,** we can use the present perfect:

> I **have drunk** three cups of coffee **this morning.**

However, you should only use this tense if you *do not* perceive the action (drinking coffee) as being *completed.*

Comment: Thank you! Excellent explanation, never thought of it this way... Live and learn.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL Thanks! I'm glad I could help!  Please mark the answer as "accepted." This will prevent others from wasting their time drafting an answer to an already (well) answered question.  Also, it will allow others who are reading this to know that my answer was "legit."

Comment: Can't find that button :(

Comment: @D4RKS0UL It should look be a grey checkmark under the downvote button.  Please look at the top answer in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see a screenshot of what button to look for.  Thanks!